# Method to print argument to console and return it unchanged

Tags: java

For a quick and very simple debugging I use in Java

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s/%s", a, b));
```

It works fine, except the cases when I quickly need to see what's being passed to some other method. Then I need temporary variable:

```
String temp = String.format("%s/%s", a, b);
System.out.println(temp);
act(temp);
```

I wonder if there's any convenience function like `trace` below, which I could statically import from any of the popular libraries?

```
act(trace(String.format("%s/%s", a, b)));
```

It would be equivalent to XQuery's [trace](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_trace.html) - just printing to `System.out` the contents and returning argument unchanged.

Sure, I could create my own util for that, but I work with multiple projects every day and maybe there's already something ready to use?

I know I could use more sophisticated approaches here, but as I said, I need it just for a dirty debugging from time to time. It should be very easy to add and remove.

Comment: You'll probably get responses with differing opinions on whether `System.out` is good for debugging (e.g. it's just a crutch, use proper unit testing; it shouldn't exist in production code; it's great for debugging, etc.). However, I don't know of anything "built-in" that does what you want. Maybe create a debugging-helper library and reference it across your projects.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I know that `System.out` is bad option for debugging, but I do it from time to time, especially when I'd like to see results from multiple calls together. Of course `System.out` almost never should exist in production code.

Comment: You should replace `System.out.println(String.format("%s/%s", a, b))` with `System.out.printf("%s/%s%n", a, b)`

Comment: @Andreas I need such solution maybe for 1 minute jut to look up what's going on in the code, then I'd like to remove it. Actual production code it not going to print anything.

Comment: If you only need it for "1 minute", have you considered using a debugger instead?

Comment: @Andreas yes, but I'd like to collect results of multiple calls and have it printed. Debugger lets me to see just a snapshot from some particular method call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like that you should use a logging library, either the Java [built-in library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html), or a 3rd-party library such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

What you then want is to add trace-level logging calls as the first statement in each method that you want to monitor. A common log message would be something like `Entering myMethod(4, 2)`, where `4` and `2` are the actual parameter values.

This way you can enable/disable logging detail level using configuration, rather than having to update/compile/package/install the code.